# Does Selenium Standalone Server 2.47.0 supports "sendKeys" command?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, sendkeys

I'm using Selenium Standalone server 2.47.0, does it support the `sendKeys` command?

Any one used `sendKeys` command in 2.47.0?

Note: I know we can use `type` command but I need `sendKeys` to work.

Comment: Can you show the code where you use `sendKeys()`? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes, I'm getting following error:

 |sendKeys | name=user
currentTest.recordFailure: Command execution failure. Please search the user group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error details from the log window.  The error message is: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Comment: @BSalunke That is an entirely different problem, you should either rewrite your question or open another one. Your problem is that you try to send text to an element which is not "interactable", i.e. an element which cannot receive text like a label, or a <br> or a ... whatever. Tell us what you really want to do with what kind of tool (looks like you are recording with selenium-ide or are you replaying some recorded script?) and show us some of your HTML page code with the element you want to type text to and a part of the script or code that runs the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `.sendkeys("texthere")` is a valid option in Selenium Standalone server 2.47.0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it definitely does, here is an example from our code:

```
protected void type(String xpath, String text) {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    element.sendKeys(text);
}
```

using 
Build info: version: '2.47.0', revision: '0e4837e', time: '2015-07-29 22:56:05'